# Is there a way to get the name of the context we're in using getContext() in Android?

Tags: android, this, android-context

I just started Android development yesterday and I'm learning a lot already. There's one thing I'm kind of getting stuck at. It's the "this" keyword (which I believe is the same as getContext()) and what context is. I won't ask that since it's been asked alot already. I think I have an idea of what context is, or maybe not. I think it would be nice if I can see what the current context is by getting the name somehow if that's even possible.

For example, at the start of a blank default application after things have loaded up. I want to call this/getContext() and get the name if possible. I expect something like "Main Activity" as the current context to come out in my LogCat right?

Maybe a code example would help (from default code)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("Main Activity", getContext().getTitle()); //getContext().getTitle() is MADE UP
}
.......
```

Thank you.

Comment: this is NOT the same as getContext.  this means the instance of the class that the function was called on-  for example if you have a class X with a method Y, then call myX.Y(), inside of Y this means myX.  getContext() is a function.  It returns a Context-  an object of either the class Context or a child of it (like Activity).  The two are never the same, however if you're in an Activity, then this is a Context because all Activities are Contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getName()` or `getSimpleName()` on the class:

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

From the Javadoc for `getName()`:

> Returns the name of the class represented by this Class. For a description of the format which is used, see the class definition of **Class**.

Javadoc for `getSimpleName()`:

> Returns the simple name of the class represented by this Class as defined in the source code. If there is no name (that is, the class is anonymous) then an empty string is returned. If the receiver is an array then the name of the underlying type with square braces appended (for example "Integer[]") is returned.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong about getContext(). It's not exactly like the "this" keyword. BUT the second line of code you have works! Thanks! Now I get this "MainActivity$1" as an output. Do you know what that $1 is? EDIT: Now I see something like MainActivity$1@3f7fcb1 when I do something like this.toString()

Comment: this.getClass().getSimpleName()

will give you just the activity name.